# Alpha aliasing issue when object is not selected

Tags: texturing, materials, transparency, antialiasing

I seem to be having an odd issue but it only happens when an object (with material that has alpha) is not selected and I assume it's only affecting the viewport.

I have 2 objects, an eye and the eye highlight (white dots).
The eye highlight has transparency because it's circular of course and it appears in front of the eye.

If I do not have the eye highlight object selected, this is how it appears:

[image]

When I do have it selected, it appears correctly:

[image]

(I have "Outline Selection" option disabled to make the problem clear).

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: If it is only affecting the viewport what issues does it cause? Viewport preview is not meant to be a full representation of final render

Comment: Hi, please use the question editor "add image" to show images, since it's free, permanent and embeds the images in your post, simplifying other's understanding...